# String replace with re sub matching the exact string

Tags: python, regex

I want to change string foo in the first line of paragraph without changing the other one. I already using pattern ^ and $ for matching the exact string like I do in perl, but still no luck. help please.

My code :

```
input_file = "foo afooa"
input_file = re.sub(r'^foo$', 'bar', input_file)
print input_file
```

So, I'm expecting result like this :

```
bar afooa
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to figure out the re.sub?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is currently `r'^foo$'` which basically matches the string 'foo' ***only***.

If you just changed it to `r'^foo'` it will match as long as 'foo' is found at the start of the string, but unlike your previous pattern it doesn't care about what follows foo.

Here is an example:

```
input_file = "foo afooa"
input_file = re.sub(r'^foo', 'bar', input_file)
input_file2 = "foob afooa"
input_file2 = re.sub(r'^foo', 'bar', input_file2)
print input_file
print input_file2
```

output:

```
bar afooa   
barb afooa
```

Now if you don't want to match a part of a string, but match the whole string 'foo' at the start of the line, then you need to add a boundary '\b' match like shown below:

```
input_file = "foo afooa"
input_file = re.sub(r'^foo\b', 'bar', input_file)
input_file2 = "foob afooa"
input_file2 = re.sub(r'^foo\b', 'bar', input_file2)
print input_file
print input_file2
```

output:

```
bar afooa
foob afooa
```

Or if you want to just replace the first occurrence of the full word 'foo', then use the pattern suggested by @DineshPundkar and limit the number of substitutions to 1 like @Tuan333 just mentioned.

So, in this case your code will look like:

```
input_file = "a foo afooa foo bazfooz"
input_file = re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', input_file, 1)
print input_file
```

output:

```
a bar afooa foo bazfooz
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), you can set `count = 1` of `re.sub()`to just change the first occurrence of the pattern. Also, remove the `^` and `$` since you donot want to search for the whole line containing only the word `foo`. Sample code:

```
import re; 
input_file = "foo afooa"; 
input_file = re.sub(r'foo', 'bar', input_file, count = 1); 
print input_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ^ and $ , use \b to match boundary.

```
>>> a="foo afooa"
>>> b= re.sub(r"\bfoo\b",'bar',a)
>>> b
'bar afooa'
>>>
```